# SQL: grades which have dropped by more than 2 bands

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on some reporting which would flag whether a student's grades have dropped by 2 or more grade bands, but can't quite seem to get the query to work.

I've simplified the data below as an example:

| Exam | StudentID | ExamDate | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bio01a | AA002 | 2022-10-20 | B |
| Bio01b | AA002 | 2023-01-10 | A |
| Phy01a | AA009 | 2022-10-20 | B |
| Phy01b | AA009 | 2022-11-10 | E |
| Phy01a | AA003 | 2022-10-20 | D |
| Phy01b | AA003 | 2022-11-10 | A |
| Bio01a | AA004 | 2022-10-20 | C |
| Bio1b | AA004 | 2023-01-10 | F |

Based on the example above, I would expect the query to turn the results

Phy01b/AA009

Bio1b/AA004

as the most recent exam grades meet the drop criteria. It doesn't matter what the initial grade is, just that the difference between the most recent and previous is 2 or more.

Doing this manually, I looked at converting the letter grade to a number (G=1, A=7) then subtracting the newest value from the oldest, if the result was <= -2, the grade drop would have been 2 or more grades, but I'm just unsure how to transpose this into a query. The grade boundaries are not uniform so the actual score of the grade cannot be used.

it's along the lines of  where max(ExamDate), Grade as grade1 AND where max(ExamDate), Grade as grade2 AND where grade1 - grade2 <= -2  but I cant get my head around it

Comment: What is MySQL version? And provide data sample as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO - we'd see columns datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a student can't have the same ExamDate more than once, this should work:

```
select Exam, StudentID, ExamDate, Grade, PreviousGrade
from table t1
left join 
    (
    select Grade as 'PreviousGrade', StudentID, 
    ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY ExamDate) as row_num
    from table
    having row_num = 2
    ) a
on table.StudentID = a.StudentID
where ascii(Grade) - ascii(PreviousGrade) >= 2
and ExamDate = 
     (
     Select max(ExamDate) 
     from table t2 
     where t1.StudentID = t2.StudentID
     )
```

It utilizes the ascii() function to convert the letter grades into their ascii value, which ascends numerically ('A' = 65, 'B' = 66, etc...)

Using row_number allows us to find the second most recent ExamDate, by assigning a row_number (1 for the most recent exam date, 2 for the 2nd most recent, etc...) for each student using the partition by clause.